# Adding ajax to like button in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app with a Post resource in which each specific post can be liked/disliked.

i want to be able to like/dislike something without having the page refresh. I've looked at a few other SO posts and all answers involve Coffeescript,, how can i solve this using vanilla js?

(I am using Friendly_id and acts_as_votable gems)

**Controller**:

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:upvote, :downvote] 
    before_action :set_post, only: [ :show , :upvote, :downvote] 
    respond_to :js, :json, :html

  def upvote
    @post.liked_by current_user
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path) 
  end 

  def downvote
    @post.disliked_by current_user
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path) 
  end 

end
```

**View**:

```
 <%= link_to like_post_path(@post), class:"like-btn", method: :put, remote: true do %> 
        <button class="btn btn-warning"> 
          <span><p><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></p></span>
        </button> 
      <% end %> 
      <%= link_to dislike_post_path(@post), class:"dislike-btn", method: :put, remote: true do %> 
        <button class="btn btn-warning"> 
          <span><p><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></p></span>
        </button> 
      <% end %> 
      <span> <%= @post.get_upvotes.size %> </span>
```

**Routes**:

```
resources :posts do
    member do
      put "like" => "posts#upvote"
      put "dislike" => "posts#downvote"
    end 
  end
```

**Models**:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_votable

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged 
end


  class User < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_voter
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

please let me know if you need any other info,, thanks!

Comment: Do you also want to update something in the view after the user upvotes or downvotes a post?

Comment: @sahil yes i would like the   <span> <%= [at]post.get_upvotes.size %> </span>    to reflect that a post has been liked/disliked

Comment: What happens to the dislike button when a user clicks on like button, is it disabled or the user can still click on disable and then the like count is reduced?

Comment: @sahil the second thing.. the user can still click and the count is reduced. Ideally i would like if there was only one button, ONLY LIKE. And when user clicks the count is increased and style changes or something and when clicked again the count decreased. Essentially so it could never go below 0. But i will settle for having two buttons if easier

Comment: Can you also post your model? I suppose you have a method to check whether a user has already liked the post or not.

Comment: @sahil edited the post... i didnt create a method but the acts_as_votable gem comes w that functionality built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am using a single method as you never want the likes count to go below zero.

Whenever the user **likes a post**, the count increments by 1 and the color of the thumbs-up icon changes(just to show a visual change).

When the user clicks on an already liked post the count of likes should be reduced by one so we should use the **unliked_by** method provided by the gem.

For implementing this we can use an upvote.js.erb file (*remember the file name should be same as your controller method name it makes the process easier*).

Then in the `.js.erb` file we can mix `ruby` with `js` and have the desired result as shown in the `upvote.js.erb` file.

I add an extra class called `liked` which changes the color of the button.

**Please Note:** I am assuming that you have a single post on a page. If you have multiple posts on a page then you should add ID's to the posts container and similarly change the `js` code in the `upvote.js.erb` file.

#### posts_controller.rb

```
  def upvote
    if !current_user.liked? @post
      @post.liked_by current_user
    elsif current_user.liked? @post
      # as the above method can also result nil if he is yet to vote
      @post.unliked_by current_user 
    end
  end
```

#### views/posts/upvote.js.erb

```
<% if current_user.liked? @post %>
 document.getElementsByClassName('like-btn')[0].className = "like-btn liked";
<% else %>
 document.getElementsByClassName('like-btn')[0].className = "like-btn";
<% end %>
document.getElementsByClassName('likes-count')[0].innerHTML="<%= @post.get_upvotes.size %>";
```

#### view.html.erb

```
<!-- Adding a class liked -->
<style>
 .liked {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>
<%= link_to like_post_path(@post), class:"like-btn", method: :put, remote: true do %> 
    <button class="btn btn-warning"> 
      <span><p><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></p></span>
    </button> 
<% end %> 
<span class="likes-count"> <%= @post.get_upvotes.size %> </span>
```

Comment: i haven't tried this but does the vote.js.erb file need to be upvote.js.erb so that it matches the name of the action in the controller? thank you btw, will try to implement this now

Comment: The color doesn't change when liked so not sure whats going on with that but the rest works. May I ask what the [0] after the getElementByClassName is referring to? Thank you so much this is amazing

Comment: As `getElementsByClassName` method gives  a collection of all elements having the same class we need to specify which element from the collection we want to work on. In the above case we wanted to change the attribute of the first element in the collecton.

Comment: Is it adding the class `liked` to the **i tag**?

Comment: i actually just removed the bootstrap btn-warning class cuz i guess it was overlapping the custom styles. i only had that class there as a test,, once removed the blue showed up fine

Comment: hey @Sahil, i'm guessing you recreated this project so you could test it out,, is there any chance you can share a repo of that if you have it? I was able to replicate w an existing project but for some reason i cant get it to work when i start an app from scratch! idk what's happening :/ if you have your example that would be awesome,,thanks a million

Comment: i figured it out, no need for repo... sorry. and thanks again

Comment: Ok, I will still be updating the answer with the repo link shortly, let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: when you are saying::  _italic_ document.getElementsByClassName('like-btn')[0].className = "like-btn liked"; _italic_ are you saying get elements with classname like-btn and give them class like-btn + class liked.. im trying to understand what the part after the equal sign (=) is doing

Comment: Yes, I am changing the value of the class attribute of that tag, and as you wanted to do it in pure vanila so I did it in this way, otherwise jQuery has a better and easier way like this: `$('.like-btn').addClass('liked');`.

Comment: oh thats awesome... if you don't mind,, what would the other two look like, is this correct? 1) $('.like-btn').addClass('liked');

Comment: 2) $('.like-btn').addClass('like-btn'); 3) not sure what to do for the innerHTML

Comment: $('.likes-count').html("<%=@post.get_upvotes.size %>");  does that seem right?

Comment: You can chain multiple methods in jquery: `$(".like-count").addClass("liked").html('<%=@post.get_upvotes.size℅>');`

Comment: @JessiAbrams, I have added a repo for [reference](https://github.com/sahil290791/voting_app).