# Adding an item to a list using ajax and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

So, I have a Ruby on Rails application where the user have a list of ingredients. When the user adds a new item to the list of ingredients I need to refresh the page so the ingredient are shown in the list. I want this to be done dynamically using Ajax, I looked up to the internet for solutions but none worked :/

Here is my HTML code(index.html.erb):

```
<%= form_for(:ingredientList, :url => {:controller => 'ingredients', :action => 'index'}, :remote => true) do |f| %>                          
     <div class ="modal-text col-md-6">
          <div class="model-subtitle">Ingrediente: </div>
          <%= f.select :value, options_for_select(@ingredient.map{ |ing| [ing.name, ing.id]}, html_options = { class: 'form-control', required: true })%>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-text col-md-6">
             <div class="model-subtitle">Quantidade: </div>
             <%= f.text_field :quantity, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "quantidade", autofocus: true %>
          </div>
          <%= f.submit :Salvar, class: 'btn btn btn-success center-block'%>
```

My controller:

```
def index
@user = User.find_by id: session[:user_id]
@ingredients = Ingredient.joins(:ingredients_users).where("user_id = ?", session[:user_id]).select("*")
@user_id = session[:user_id]
@ingredient = Ingredient.all

respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html
    if params[:ingredientList]
        @userIngredient = IngredientsUser.new
        @userIngredient.ingredient_id = params[:ingredientList][:value]
        @userIngredient.quantity = params[:ingredientList][:quantity]
        @userIngredient.user_id = @user.id
        if @userIngredient.save
            flash[:success] = "Ingredient saved!"
        else
            @userIngredient.errors.full_messages.each do |error| 
                flash[:alert] = error
            end
        end
    end
end
```

end

I don't know if I make something wrong(probably as is not working) or if I forgot to add something. Do any of you know how to solve this?

Comment: You can try something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40167714/adding-ajax-to-like-button-in-rails-app/40168360#40168360), the concept remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I say this without knowing what your `app/views/ingredients/index.js` file looks like, but I think you have it almost correct.

As soon as you call `format.js` and `format.html` in your controller, it will go ahead and render the corresponding view (eg: a`pp/views/ingredients/index.js`). Any code that comes after `format.js` and `format.html` will be executed only **AFTER** the rendering is complete.

So in your case, what happens is that the rendering is done prior to actually processing the input (initializing the ingredient, trying to save it, ...). Try moving `format.js` and `format.html` to the end of the action code:

```
def index
    @user = User.find_by id: session[:user_id]
    @ingredients = Ingredient.joins(:ingredients_users).where("user_id = ?", session[:user_id]).select("*")
    @user_id = session[:user_id]
    @ingredient = Ingredient.all

    respond_to do |format|
        if params[:ingredientList]
            @userIngredient = IngredientsUser.new
            @userIngredient.ingredient_id = params[:ingredientList][:value]
            @userIngredient.quantity = params[:ingredientList][:quantity]
            @userIngredient.user_id = @user.id
            if @userIngredient.save
                 flash[:success] = "Ingredient saved!"
            else
                @userIngredient.errors.full_messages.each do |error| 
                     flash[:alert] = error
                end
            end
        end

        format.js
        format.html
    end
end
```

All of that said, you're "violating" the Rails conventions. An index action should primarily be used to **get** a series of objects. Saving data should be either via the **create** (if it's a new record) or **update** action (if it's a change to an existing record).